# Cordova Android app storage permissions keep turning off

Tags: android, cordova, android-manifest

I have the permissions setup in my AndroidManifest.xml file that look like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

However, everytime I run cordova build android, then cordova run android the permission in system settings for app storage is disabled. Why isn't this option automatically enabled when I have my manifest file setup with the above config?